# localhost refused to connect on redirect

Tags: php, ubuntu, ssl, web, apache2

I am trying to redesign a website and i've set up localhost with copy of the server website.
But connection is refused after redirect.
I have this code

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://localhost/vfino/v11">
```

the original is

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.vfconsult.com.pt/">
```

i also have this .htacces in root

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/new/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/imagens/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/v11/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ v11/$1 [L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^vfconsult\.com\.pt$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.vfconsult\.com\.pt$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.vfconsult\.com\.pt\/v11/$1" [R=301,L]
```

I've tried to change the remote url to localhost but connection still refused.
I apreciate very much your help.
Thanks.

Comment: You have a copy of the website on the client machine?

Comment: "Connection refused" means there's no webserver running. Are you sure you started the webserver on the client machine?

Comment: It's probably better to setup a vhost on apache and a DNS entry in your hosts to have 
vfconsult.com.pt point to 127.0.0.1 . However you may need to use a self-signed SSL certificate. If any of these are unclear terms then google them.

Comment: @barmar I have a copy on local machine

Comment: It sounds like you haven't started the webserver on the local machine.

Comment: Or maybe you haven't opened port 80 on the firewall.

Comment: its open and webserver is running, because i have other websites on localhost and they work as usual

Comment: @ apokryfos . I setup a virtual host that works fine , but the requests go to remote host not localhost

Comment: modify your `hosts` file (in linux that's in /etc/hosts in windows it's in .. C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) have the hostname direct to 127.0.0.1 to prevent a normal DNS lookup from happening.

Comment: i have that . i dont understand whats happenning.

Comment: i have access http://vfconsult.com.pt/ it goes to localhost but if i access vfconsult.com.pt/v11/  it redirects to https://www.vfconsult.com.pt/v11/ that is the remote website(production)

Answer (score 0):

If i have access `http://vfconsult.com.pt/` it goes to localhost but if i access `vfconsult.com.pt/v11/`  it redirects to `https://www.vfconsult.com.pt/v11/` that is the remote website(production)